# How to manage memory for objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, memory-management, iphone-sdk-3.0

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    MyObject *objecto;
}
```

I have an object that I declare as a private variable (I think this is how you do a private variable in objective c).

Do I have to retain and release it?

For example if I have a function should I be retaining it as soon as it has been assigned?  Should I be using properties to do this always?

```
initWithMyObject: MyObject *input
```

Comment: the answer is yes and properties are a great way to save time putting in the retain release code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would suggest to read memory management guide ...

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 1):

Four Basic Rules To Allocate and Release Memory

1. If you own it, release it.
2. If you don’t own it, don’t release it.
3. Override dealloc in your classes to release the fields that you own.
4. Never call dealloc directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to create objecto (alloc/init) in your init method of MyClass.  And release objecto in the dealloc of MyClass.